# merge 3 bytearray into single one in c#

Tags: c#, byte, arrays

I have three **bytearray** having length **40000**. I want to merge bytearray index 0,1 of a byte array1, then index 0,1 of **bytearaay2** and index of **bytearray3** to **40000** length.

Like this:

Scenario:

```
a1[0]a1[1]a2[0]a2[1]a3[0]a3[1]a1[2]a1[3]a2[2]a2[3]a3[2]a3[3] ...

and then so on up to 40000.
```

So finally i want to merge 3 byte array to single one as a pair of grouping.

Comment: What's wrong with a very simple loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing that all arrays (say, `source1`, `source2`, `source3`) are of the *same length* and this length is an *even number* (`40000`):

```
  Byte[] result = new Byte[source1.Length * 3];

  for (int i = 0; i < source1.Length / 2; ++i) {
    result[i * 6] = source1[2 * i];
    result[i * 6 + 1] = source1[2 * i + 1];

    result[i * 6 + 2] = source2[2 * i];
    result[i * 6 + 3] = source2[2 * i + 1];

    result[i * 6 + 4] = source3[2 * i];
    result[i * 6 + 5] = source3[2 * i + 1];
  }
```

just a *for loop*.

Answer (score 2):

```
int resultIndex = 0;
int groupingIndex = 0;
int maxLength = 40000;
while (resultIndex < maxLength)
{
   result[resultIndex] = source1[groupingIndex];
   resultIndex++;
   if (resultIndex >= maxLength) break;
   result[resultIndex] = source1[groupingIndex+1];
   resultIndex++;
   if (resultIndex >= maxLength) break;
   result[resultIndex] = source2[groupingIndex];
   resultIndex++;
   if (resultIndex >= maxLength) break;
   result[resultIndex] = source2[groupingIndex+1];
   resultIndex++;
   if (resultIndex >= maxLength) break;
   result[resultIndex] = source3[groupingIndex];
   resultIndex++;
   if (resultIndex >= maxLength) break;
   result[resultIndex] = source3[groupingIndex+1];
   resultIndex++;
   if (resultIndex >= maxLength) break;
   groupingIndex = groupIndex + 2;
}
```

You can obviously break this up using some helper functions. You can also simplify the loop (removing the if checks) if you allow for the result to initially be 3 times the size of the source length, and then trim to the appropriate size after the interleaving.

Answer (score 0):

In **C# 3.0** you can use **LINQ**:

```
Byte[] combinedByte = bytearray1.Concat(bytearray2).ToArray();
Byte[] combinedByte = combinedByte.Concat(bytearray3).ToArray();
```

Comment: He wants the array values interleaved not concatenated

Comment: Actually it concatenate the bytearray1 and bytearray2. So the ordering is bytearray1(all the bytes from byteaaray1 ) and then bytearray2(all the bytes from bytearray2). But i want bytearray1[0]bytearray1[1]bytearray2[0]bytearray2[1] and then so on.
In pair of two 0,1 index 2,3 index and 4,5 and so on of all the three byte array.

Comment: I edit my post... with this method merge 3 byte array to single one

Comment: Actually it concatenate the bytearray1 and bytearray2. So the ordering is bytearray1(all the bytes from byteaaray1 ) and then bytearray2(all the bytes from bytearray2). But i want bytearray1[0]bytearray1[1]bytearray2[0]bytearray2[1] and then so on. In pair of two 0,1 index 2,3 index and 4,5 and so on of all the three byte array